# SQL only return top row per indentfier in select

Tags: sql, datetime, select, join, distinct

I'm only trying to return the top row per Num,  in DB.  In the example below D1001 should only have the first row.

```
cte_num 
as
(
select distinct num from cte_PRB157
)
SELECT b.*,c.*, (b.Count - c.Count) as 'increase'
FROM cte_num 
left JOIN cte_PRB157 as b on cte_num.Num = b.Num 
left join cte_PRB157 as c on b.num = c.num and b.Idx <> c.idx 
where b.DateTime > @eom
ORDER BY cte_num.Num, b.datetime desc
```

However my select then turns into multiple rows for num.  I only want the top most row per num.

```
160697 D1001 799 2013-12-02 00:00:00.000 PRB157     150641 D1001 778 2013-10-31 00:00:00.000 PRB157     21
160697 D1001 799 2013-12-02 00:00:00.000 PRB157     196836 D1001 770 2013-09-01 00:00:00.000 PRB157     29
160703 D1002 16888 2013-12-02 00:00:00.000 PRB157     150647 D1002 16949 2013-10-31 00:00:00.000 PRB157     -61
160703 D1002 16888 2013-12-02 00:00:00.000 PRB157     196835 D1002 18770 2013-09-01 00:00:00.000 PRB157     -1882
```

I know I'm missing something simple

Comment: add limit 1 at the end

Comment: I'm not sure that is I want.   In the example.  I want rows 1 and 3.  The top one for d1001 and d1002.

Comment: how about something like SELECT num , MAX(datetime) FROM table GROUP BY num

Comment: it's hard to help without column names